# Cakephp 3 upgrade tools unable to access file

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I try to use Cakephp 3 [upgrade tool](https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade).

I installed composer, I made this:

```
cd /path/to/upgrade
bin/cake upgrade all /home/mark/Sites/my-app
```

Then I get tons of error like this in windows command shell.

```
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\a2d4223f62e3499a84b6ca30be24bfdb4cb6de40''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\Helper\CacheHelper.php
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\7fbe7651712387f351b1eb670b14c18e1161fcb8''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper.php
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\2301f9bed1167ddb29ca4e06706d0d21bd015766''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\Helper\NumberHelper.php
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\e71af0cbc7df7ff76e801c5fb06ec07ee7f45233''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\1b04b5a763ca4e798d1e176111e49008b7486724''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\Helper\TextHelper.php
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\f8ead667c131610c1f70f38d10c7122b34d9a7fc''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\Helper\TimeHelper.php
error: Could not access ''C:\mydir\upgrade\tmp\upgrade\4a2c2e7f3f7e9faf744d10e6e1f3ff24bead7f08''
Update C:\mydir\myapp\lib\Cake\View\HelperCollection.php
```

I run command shell as administrator. What would be the problem ? When I check folder during operation, I can see that temporary file exists in folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the very same issue. Here's a description of the issue :

- This is a Git error
- Git command that fails is called by /upgradeTool/src/Shell/Task/StageTask.php on line 176 by exec() php function (seems different for you)
- command to run git looks like this : `git diff --no-index 'T:\Logiciels\CakePHP_3_upgradeTool\tmp\upgrade\c5d0aaadb3484d4bfe56bdfc4553b444f6789e66' 'T:\Logiciels\CakePHP_3_upgradeTool\tmp\upgrade\4a6662f82cd03d46b515c28f7d77ef8a64c08cfd'`

**EDIT (2015-07-12)**

As ndm noted, *"the source of the problem is the single quote usage in the arguments for the git command, the Windows CLI will pass them as if they belong to the file path"*

I changed this line (/upgradeTool/src/Shell/Task/StageTask.php on line 176) from :

```
exec("git diff --no-index "$oPath" "$uPath"', $output);
```

to :

```
exec('git diff --no-index "'.$oPath.'" "'.$uPath.'"', $output);
```

Now the process seems complete. Many many thanks !

Comment: Did you make a PR with your fixes in the source code? That would be good.

Answer (score 0):

After tryouts I found solution.  As DarXnake noted, problem is git.

When you install git it asks whether you want to use git from command line or not. Default option is `Use Git Bash only`. I had selected that option.

Now I updated git and when setup asked for install type, I selected `Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt`. Then I retried cakephp upgrade and I didn't get any access error.

[image]

Comment: I would be surprised if that really fixed the problem, because the source of the problem is the single quote usage in the arguments for the git command, the Windows CLI will pass them as if they belong to the file path. If GIT weren't in your PATH env variable already, then you'd have received a totally different error message.

Comment: I have had git path in my env variables before this change. After that step error disappeared and upgrade worked.

Comment: Might be true that it worked afterwards, however it's most probably not because of the GIT upgrade, but more likely because in the second run, the files were already modified, and only had to be moved, so that it wouldn't reach the problematic `git` command anymore. Try it again with a Cake 2.x project where files need to be moved and modified, I'm pretty sure it will fail again.